# How to define lambda function for Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Using Pandas Dataframe, I intend to store values inside a Dataframe calculated from data stored in the same Dataframe.

Trying without lambda, it does not work properly:

```
def fences(data):
    """
    Returns with the fences defined based on statistical quartiles
    
    data: Raw data
    
    return: DataFrame with X,Y,Z in columns ans Q1,Q2,Q3,IQR,F_l,F_h
    """
    
    dp = pd.DataFrame(index=["Q1","Q2","Q3","IQR","F_l","F_h"], columns=["X","Y","Z"])
    
    """Calculate quartiles"""
    dp.iloc[0:1,0:3] = record.iloc[:,1:4].quantile(.25)
    dp.iloc[1:2,0:3] = record.iloc[:,1:4].quantile(.5)
    dp.iloc[2:3,0:3] = record.iloc[:,1:4].quantile(.75)
    
    """Calculate IQRs"""
    dp.iloc[3:4,0:3] = dp.iloc[2:3,0:3] - dp.iloc[0:1,0:3]
    
    return dp
```

It reports an error such as "**ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (1,3)**" although I thought it may work, because the index and size look good and fit to each other:

[image]

So I believe, the solution might be a lambda function, although it is not so obvious for me...

Anyone could help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

The shapes are the following:

Q1:
[image]

Q3:
[image]

So it was assumed that after the subtraction it gives (1,3), although it ends up (2,3) which causes the error...

[image]

Does the row-index causes this mess?

Comment: You are on the right track. You did not provide any data for us to replicate your error. 

From what I can guess, error seems to happen from the line when you are performing subtractions on arrays. For subtraction of arrays, you have to make sure your arrays are of the same dimension and size.

Comment: @jakelime Thanks. You are right, I forgot to provide some details... I updated the question with respect to the shapes and it seems that my assumption was wrong: the subtraction results a shape of (2,3) which is not so clear, why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to rephrase your question:

```py
import pandas as pd

dp = pd.DataFrame(
    [[8.3275, 0.8725, -2.0275], [4.03, -6.215, -6.7025]],
    columns=["X", "Y", "Z"],
    index=["Q1", "Q2"],
)
print(dp)

a = dp.iloc[0:1, 0:3]
b = dp.iloc[1:2, 0:3]

print(f"a=\n{a}")
print(f"b=\n{b}")

c1 = a - b
print(f"c1=\n{c1}")
```

Your question is "Why subtraction of the 2 vectors `a` and `b` returns `NaN`"?

```
## Pandas dataframe
         X       Y       Z
Q1  8.3275  0.8725 -2.0275
Q2  4.0300 -6.2150 -6.7025

a=
         X       Y       Z
Q1  8.3275  0.8725 -2.0275

b=
       X      Y       Z
Q2  4.03 -6.215 -6.7025

# Results of subtraction
c1=
     X   Y   Z
Q1 NaN NaN NaN
Q2 NaN NaN NaN
```

## Answer

```
c2 = a.reset_index(drop=True) - b.reset_index(drop=True)
print(f"c2=\n{c2}")
```

`a - b` didn't work because the `iloc` takes a snapshot of the dataframe which took into account of the index as well. The rows are not simply just "numbers", but have additional information such as being located differently `Q1` and `Q3` index.

You are looking for simply subtracting of the numbers.

One way to do it is to simply use `iloc` + `reset_index()` to return a copy of simply the scalar numbers.

```
c2=
        X       Y      Z
0  4.2975  7.0875  4.675
```